# Which is the proper site to ask about commands on Arch Linux?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I see the most popular site on Stack Exchange about Linux is Ask Ubuntu, however, my question is a Arch Linux related question (commands/services).

Comment: There is also [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Stack Exchange about Linux is Ask Ubuntu" no, Ask Ubuntu is one site to ask about Ubuntu. The most popular  for asking questions about linux is Super User.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling `Arch Linux site:unix.stackexchange.com` returns 307 results vs 270 results with `Arch Linux site:superuser.com` so I would say Unix & Linux StackExchange is better.

To answer more generally, I refer to https://stackexchange.com/sites since newer sites which are more focused tend to be better forums for targeted questions.